# Segmentation fault when parsing c string into pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

The function makearg is supposed to count the number of words in a char array and also break each word up into their own spot in a pointer array.
Segmentation fault seems to be a problem with the strncpy function.

```
int makearg(char s[], char ***args);

int main(){

  char **args = (char**)(malloc(100));

  char *str = "ls is a -l file";
  int argc;
  argc = makearg(str, &args);

  printf("%d", argc);
  printf("%c", '\0');

  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < argc; i++){
    puts(args);
    printf("%c", '\n');
  }
  return 0;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////

int makearg(char s[], char ***args){

  int argc = 0;
  int charc = 0;
  int wordstart = 0;

  while(1){
    if(s[charc] == '\0'){
      strncpy(*args[argc], s + wordstart, charc - wordstart);
      args[argc][(charc - wordstart) + 1] = '\0';

      argc++;
      break;
  }

  if(s[charc] == ' '){
    strncpy(*args[argc], s + wordstart, charc - wordstart);
    args[argc][(charc -  wordstart) + 1] = '\0';

    wordstart = charc + 1;
    argc++;
    charc++;
  }

  else{
    charc++;
    }
  }
  return argc;
}
```

Comment: 1)`char **args = (char**)malloc(100*sizeof(char*));` 2)args[index] is not initialize(memory area need for store by strncpy). 3)`*args[argc],` --> `(*args)[argc],` when `char ***args;`

Comment: 4)`puts(args);` --> `puts(args[i]);` 5)`args[argc][(charc - wordstart) + 1] = '\0';` --> `args[argc][charc - wordstart] = '\0';`

Comment: 6)`int makearg(char s[], char ***args){` : No need for triple pointer because it is not rewritten. 7) `printf("%c", '\0');` no meaning

Comment: @BLUEPIXY write an answer

Comment: @Eric what was `printf("%c", '\0');` trying to achieve

Comment: Increase the warning level of your compiler and tell it to treat warnings as errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int makearg(const char s[], char ***args);

int main(void){
    char **args = NULL;
    const char *str = "ls is a -l file";
    int argc = makearg(str, &args);

    printf("argc : %d\n", argc);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++){
        puts(args[i]);
        free(args[i]);
    }
    free(args);
    return 0;
}

int wordCount(const char *s){
    char prev = ' ';
    int wc = 0;

    while(*s){
        if(isspace(prev) && !isspace(*s)){
            ++wc;
        }
        prev = *s++;
    }
    return wc;
}

int makearg(const char s[], char ***args /*out*/){
    int argc = wordCount(s);
    int len;

    if(argc == 0){
        *args = NULL;
        return 0;
    }
    *args = malloc(argc * sizeof(char*));
    argc = 0;
    while(1){
        while(isspace(*s))
            ++s;
        if(EOF==sscanf(s, "%*s%n", &len))
            break;
        (*args)[argc] = malloc(len + 1);
        strncpy((*args)[argc], s, len);
        (*args)[argc++][len] = '\0';
        s += len;
    }
    return argc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You allocated space for the `args` array of pointers, but you never allocate space for the strings you intend to store in them, so when you try to store the strings in `makearg`, you are interpreting whatever random garbage is there as a pointer, and that's not going to work.

Also, you only allocate 100 *bytes* for the pointer array -- it's not clear how many
words you expect to be able to split, but the `malloc` call should probably look more like

```
char **args = malloc(MAX_WORDS * sizeof(char *));  /* no cast required */
```

then follow that with a loop to do MAX_WORDS more `malloc` calls, in order to initialize `args` with valid pointers.

Comment: when allocating memory like this, it isn't allocated in ROM right? I am still getting a segfault when i add the null character to each word

Comment: The malloc call [should not have a cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)